# How to store or retrieve embed codes in Node/Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, iframe, embed

I'd like to show embedded video and audio from Youtube, Soundcloud and other services. I have two ideas on how to do this and am open to others.

1. Put the full embed code in the Mongo DB for each item. So the code will be `{{ item.embedCode }}` in Angular. This seems easy, but if the embed code ever changes I have to go update every item in the database.
2. Do the logic to retrieve the right embed code in the Angular code. So `if ($scope.embedItem.type == 'youtube') { $scope.embedItem.embedCode = "YOUTUBE-EMBED-CODE-HERE" }`. The drawback here is it increases the size of the app, increasing load times. I could potentially have hundreds of embed types.

Just want to know what other methods are out there.

Answer (score 1):

> ($scope.embedItem.type == 'youtube') { $scope.embedItem.embedCode = "YOUTUBE-EMBED-CODE-HERE" }

that line has less than 100 bytes, if you have 200 embed codes, that's 20kB of (uncompressed) size. And if you used a lookup array, it's really only the size of the array itself that matters, i.e.

```
{ 'youtube' : 'http://youtube.com/...' }, 
   ...
```

Compare that to 120kB of (minified) AngularJS alone - it shouldn't trouble you.

The key is that it's *very likely* that the embed codes will change, so you'll right now have to write a piece of code for the modification which must be tested, maintained, updated, deployed, be usable, etc...

If, in a more distant future, you really end up having implemented 1,000 services to embed, you could send only the relevant subset to the client and combine that with client-side storage... This is easy to optimize when it's really important.

I'd suggest to focus on getting the functionality ready, optimize only when required.

Comment: Well, the embed code could actually be much longer than the placeholder I used.

Comment: Let's say you display 100 such links per site, and the links follow some kind of long tail distribution such that 50 come from youtube, 20 from vimeo, and then there are some smaller ones. Then you *save* a lot of traffic by transferring the embed code only once for each provider, rather than sending 50 almost identical youtube links.

Comment: Check out my self-submitted answer below if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something like [iFramely](https://github.com/itteco/iframely) will get embed codes for hundreds of sites by just submitting your URL to it. It's an open source Node app which you run on your server. There is also a cloud version which is paid.

There are other services like this, like [embedly](http://embed.ly), which is entirely a paid service.

Another one is [NoEmbed](http://noembed.com), which is also free and open source, but is written in Perl. Since this question is about a Node app, I think using a Node solution will be more familiar.

None of these are Angular modules, so there will be no bloating of the code beyond simple `$http` requests to the iFramely/embedly service.